# What can I do about my DateListPlot plotting incorrectly?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have noticed that

```
DateListPlot[{Callout[{DateObject[{2016, 4, 5}, "Day", 
     "Gregorian", -5.`], 9.81`}, "HTC Vive"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2018, 4, 5}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    13.09`}, "HTC Vive Pro"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2016, 3, 28}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    9.81`}, "Oculus Rift CV1"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2019, 5, 22}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    14.4`}, "Oculus Quest"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2019, 5, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    11.07`}, "Valve Index"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2017, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    17.45`}, "Pimax 4K"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2018, 11, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    21.33`}, "Pimax 5K Plus"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2019, 2, 19}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    22.58`}, "Pimax 8K"], 
  Callout[{DateObject[{2019, 10, 3}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    13.09`}, "HTC Vive Cosmos"]}, Joined -> False]
```

is plotting incorrectly in Mathematica:

> [image]

In particular, the "Pimax 4K" is plotting as the maximum point, when it should be the "Pimax 5K". Many other points are clearly also wrong.

What is causing this?

#### Edit

Suggests in the comments fix this issue. But is this still a bug in Mathematica, or is the way it's being plotted the expected behavior?

Comment: Applying `SortBy[First]` to the data will work around this issue.

Comment: ... or wrap each data point with List; i.e., `DateListPlot[
 List /@ ..., Joined -> False]`.

Comment: ... or `DateListPlot[ Sort@{...} ,Joined -> False]`. Looks like this is a bug. With unsorted input data, the same issue arises with all wrappers I tried (`Labeled`, `Style`, `Button`...)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug caused by incorrect handling of unsorted input data with wrappers. It is easily fixed by wrapping input data with `Sort` (or `SortBy[First]` as suggested by Brett).

Additional examples of the issue with wrappers `Callout`, `Tooltip`, `Labeled`, `Style` and `Button`:

***Callout***

```
data0 = {Callout@{{2019, 11}, 2}, Callout@{{2019, 4}, 1}, Callout@{{2019, 7}, 3}};

Row[DateListPlot[ToExpression@#, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {"data0", "Sort@data0"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

***Tooltip***

```
data1 = {Tooltip[#, DateObject[#[[1]]]] &@{{2019, 11}, 2}, 
   Tooltip[#, DateObject[#[[1]]]] &@{{2019, 4}, 1}, 
   Tooltip[#, DateObject[#[[1]]]] &@{{2019, 7}, 3}};

Row[DateListPlot[ToExpression@#, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {"data1", "Sort@data1"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

***Labeled***

```
data2 = {Labeled@{{2019, 11}, 2}, Labeled@{{2019, 4}, 1}, 
   Labeled@{{2019, 7}, 3}};

Row[DateListPlot[ToExpression@#, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {"data2", "Sort@data2"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

***Style***

```
data3 = {Style[{{2019, 11}, 2}, Red], Style[{{2019, 4}, 1}, Green], 
   Style[{{2019, 7}, 3}, Blue]};

Row[DateListPlot[ToExpression@#, Mesh -> Full, 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[.05], ImageSize -> 400, 
    PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {"data3", "Sort@data3"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

***Button***

```
data4 = {{{2019, 11}, 2}, 
   Button[{{2019, 4}, 1}, Speak[DateString[{2019, 4}, {"MonthName", " ", "Year"}]]], 
   Button[{{2019, 7}, 3}, Speak[DateString[{2019, 7}, {"MonthName", " ", "Year"}]]]};

Row[DateListPlot[ToExpression@#, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 24}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {"data4", "Sort@data4"},  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

In the last example, click on the plot markers to hear the label.